# Using new Thread instead of Task.Run on BlockingCollection

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await

Our code has sometime problems in returning

I have a producer/consumer application which start multiple consumers waiting on BlockingCollection (named queue).

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
     {
     try
      {
           await InboundQueue(stoppingToken.Value, queueProcessorId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                               
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException ocex)
      {
                                
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
                                
      }
      }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
```

Every consumer is blocked in TryTake method before processing processMessage.

```
if (!_queue.TryTake(out var message, timeToWait, cancellationToken))
{
..
await processMessage((T)message).ConfigureAwait(false);
..
}
```

In processMessage we call multiple times database doing async/await, calling httpclient with async/await and even doing in some cases Task.Run to do things and not wait for completition.

It happens quite offen that await is taking some time to finish. We added in some code inside processMessage additional ConfigureAwait(false) and it helped in some cases. Still slow await happens.

https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread
Reading this post we will change code to use "new Thread" istead of "Task.Factory.StartNew".

1.Because we will have a standard thread created for running consumers do we need inside processMesssage method additional ConfigureAwait(false) calling async httpclient or database?

2.processMessage has will have own thread and can be easily sync. Can we do safely .Result on libs that request async calling?

3.How can we debug this situation? Note: By tracing network we found that https calls and database calls are always fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Collect an ETW trace using PerfView and anlayze it to see where time is being wasted.

Comment: @DarkoZa [.NET Async Tool for performance profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/analyze-async?view=vs-2019) and [Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2019) can become your best friends.

Comment: We would like to analyze production environment and we don't have visual studio installqtions there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the original code: `StartNew` doesn't understand `async` code. Specifically, the `LongRunning` flag is pretty much meaningless there, because it only applies to the part of the code until it hits the first `await`.

> I have a producer/consumer application which start multiple consumers waiting on BlockingCollection (named queue).

> Every consumer is blocked in TryTake method before processing processMessage.

So you end up blocking a bunch of thread pool threads, and I suspect that is what is actually causing your problem (especially if this pattern is repeated elsewhere).

> It happens quite offen that await is taking some time to finish.

This sound like thread pool exhaustion, which can happen if thread pool threads are used to block on a regular basis.

> We added in some code inside processMessage additional ConfigureAwait(false) and it helped in some cases.

Doubtful. On thread pool threads, `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect.

> https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread Reading this post we will change code to use "new Thread" istead of "Task.Factory.StartNew".

Well, it's important to understand the context, and why the original code is bad. (Side note: David points out "Don't use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` with `async` code as this will create a new thread which will be destroyed after first `await`", which is the reason for my first paragraph above).

The problem is that thread pool threads are being blocked on a regular basis. If it's just a couple threads at startup, I personally would think that's OK and just allow the thread pool to inject replacements. But if the code is regularly blocking thread pool threads, that's a problem and can cause thread pool exhaustion.

Now, regarding *solutions*, one solution is indeed to use manual threads, but that's not the solution I would recommend. IMO a far better solution is to remove the blocking.

Specifically, replace the `BlockingCollection<T>` queue with something that's `async`-friendly like `System.Threading.Channels`. Or, if you are interested in a somewhat larger refactor, look into TPL Dataflow.

Removing the blocking is a far better solution than adding manual threads IMO. That said, to answer your specific questions:

> Because we will have a standard thread created for running consumers do we need inside processMesssage method additional ConfigureAwait(false) calling async httpclient or database?

For a manual thread - just like a thread pool thread - `ConfigureAwait(false)` is meaningless.

> processMessage has will have own thread and can be easily sync.

It would *have* to be synchronous, actually. Custom threads can't be asynchronous (the thread exits at the first `await`). Unless you install a single-threaded context, but then `ConfigureAwait(false)` *does* have meaning. And that gets pretty complex.

> Can we do safely .Result on libs that request async calling?

That depends on the library. But they would *probably* be fine. Note: `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is like `Result` except it doesn't wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

> How can we debug this situation?

That's a good question. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall) may help; essentially, capture a performance analysis and look for regular thread injection events. You can then find a commonly blocking API by taking a snapshot and examining the thread stacks.

Comment: Do you suggest to replace Task.Factory.StartNew with Task.Run?

Comment: If you need to queue work to the thread pool thread, then yes.

Comment: We need transactions to run in parallel.

Comment: I believe you need *concurrency*; I don't see a need for parallelism. You can get asynchronous concurrency just by using `async` methods (with `Task.WhenAll` if you need to join the results).